# correr ejemplo de libreria de github

Tags: javascript, nodejs

estoy intentando probar una libreria https://github.com/karpathy/svmjs

este es el codigo el cual esta en la pagina

```
// include the library
<script src="./svmjs/lib/svm.js"></script>
<script>
data = [[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]];
labels = [-1, 1, 1, -1];
svm = new svmjs.SVM();
svm.train(data, labels, {C: 1.0}); // C is a parameter to SVM
testlabels = svm.predict(testdata);
</script>
```

no se como hacerlo funcionar, me sale este error

> ReferenceError: svmjs is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Una es descargarlo y usarlo en esa ruta relativa... La otra es usar el archivo raw.

1. Ve a este link: https://github.com/karpathy/svmjs/blob/master/lib/svm.js
2. Luego toca donde dice raw.

Te va a llevar a este enlace.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karpathy/svmjs/master/lib/svm.js

Entonces lo único que hay que hacer es cambiar esto:

```
<script src="./svmjs/lib/svm.js"></script>
```

... por esto:

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karpathy/svmjs/master/lib/svm.js"></script>
```

Eso, solo si no está descargado, y si no se quieren usar rutas relativas... Es probable que de esta manera salte el CORS... En ese caso, la mejor manera es descargarlo.

Comment: Esto no es una solución a su problema, claramente el está usando el ejemplo y el script de forma local

Comment: @JoriusR En ese caso, lo que hay que hacer es quitar el punto y barra... Cambiar `src="./svmjs...` por `src="svmjs...`.

Comment: Tampoco me generó ningún error el remover el `./` de mi `src`

Answer (score 1):

Descargué el archivo `svm.js` para probar de forma local, mi estructura de archivos es la siguiente:

```
SVM // directorio raíz
---- index.html
---- svm.js
```

Este es mi `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SVM</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="svm.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    data = [[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]];
    labels = [-1, 1, 1, -1];
    svm = new svmjs.SVM();
    svm.train(data, labels, {C: 1.0}); // C is a parameter to SVM
    testlabels = svm.predict(testdata);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Me funcionó correctamente y no logré reproducir tu error, sin embargo me lanzó:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: testdata is not defined(…)

Lo corregí cambiando esta línea de código:

```
testlabels = svm.predict(testdata);
```

por esta:

```
testlabels = svm.predict(data);
```

Prueba intentándolo tal cual te estoy explicando en mi respuesta a ver que tal